# VueJS: Computed Property inside a loop

Tags: vue.js, methods, computed-properties

My scenario is that of the picture:
[image]

I have some transaction headers and transaction details. The screenshot is a pop-up dialog for editing a transaction...
One transaction could be a member ship fee. If a member pays a fee (see 1) then I want to be able  to enter the month related to the fee.
Each "Buchungsvorgang" (transaction detail) is being looped through with v-for:

```
<v-row
                        v-for="(item, index) in editedItem.transactionDetail"
                        :key="index"
                        dense
                        align="center"
                        class="mb-2"
                      >
```

I also want to show the months for which a member has already paid previously.
I have set it by:
When the name (see figure 1) is changed call a method:

```
async showMonths (idPerson) {
      try {
        const response = await this.$axios.$get(`/api/api.php/records/transactions?filter=idPerson,eq,${idPerson}&size=5`)
        this.lastMonths = response.records
          .map((item) => {
            return `${this.$moment(item.month, 'YYYY-MM').format('MMM YY')} - (${new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(item.Amount)})`
          })
          .join(' //  ')
      } catch (e) {
        this.lastMonths = e.message
      }
    }
```

This works perfectly. It's an async function as it always picks up the latest info directly from the database.

So each time, if a change the member (see number 1), the output changes.

My problem: It only changes when someone triggers the change event of the form. If I open the dialog, number two would be empty because no one triggered the event in the first place.

[image]
This is the way it looks when I open the dialog.

Question:
Can I use a async computed property here and as a parameter, pass the editedItem.transactionId to the prop in order to retrieve the data?
Or can I put the method inside the data () - function? I want the output to be visible all the time, not just if someone clicks on a field.

I have created to small codepen to illustrate the problem:
https://codepen.io/rasenkantenstein/pen/qBdZepM

The first form (person.name) is meaningless. However, the city is the variable equal to figure 1. The result should be printed as the :message property of figure 2 (city).

How - when loading the codepen - can I populate both details?

Comment: Why can't you manually call `showMonths` when the dialog loads?

Comment: Hi Dan. I am not sure where to put the trigger in a way that it calls the proper detail position. The position depends on the item inside the v-for loop.

Comment: It sounds to me like you only need to call `showMonths` in the `created` hook of the dialog, using the first id.  Otherwise, I suggest creating a minimal reproducible example of the problem.  The only code shown here is the `showMonths` method.

Comment: I have added a paragraph with a codepen example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your codepen that does what I think you want, see [example](https://codepen.io/bcronje/pen/KKMYObW).

Essentially, you just set your messages on either created or mounted hooks:

```
  created: function () {
    this.people.forEach((item, i) => {
      Vue.set(this.message, i, item.country)
    })
  }
```

The key thing to note above is the use of `Vue.set`, since Vue cannot detect changes to an array when you directly set an item with the index, see the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) around this. So I recommend you use `Vue.set` inside your `changeCity` function as well.

Comment: THank you, that worked as a boilerplate. There was one more difficulty to overcome. I wanted to reach out for the database to retrieve the message for the real scenario. That was also possible:
`created: async function () {
    await all.Promise(this.people.forEach( async (item, i) => {
      const resMessage = await this.axios.get('...')
      Vue.set(this.message, i, item.country)
    }))
  }`